# how to uncheck radio button in php using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, radio-button

i want to uncheck radio buttons but first one is selected as default. i used this code but this doesn't work for me. this code gives "Please select one of these options" and when i remove required attribute unchecked radio button is posted and its unknown to controller

```
$("#FIRST").prop('checked',false);
$("#SECOND").prop('checked',false);
$("#THIRD").prop('checked',false);
```

i also use this one but it also not worked for me

```
var radio = $("FIRST");
radio.prop('checked', false).button("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

**For jQuery < 1.6:**

To check/uncheck a checkbox, use the attribute checked and alter that. With jQuery you can do:

```
$('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', true); // Checks it
$('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', false); // Unchecks it
```

Cause you know, in HTML, it would look something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" checked="checked" /> <!-- Checked -->
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" /> <!-- Unchecked -->
```

However, you cannot trust the .attr() method to get the value of the checkbox (if you need to). You will have to rely in the .prop() method.

**So for jQuery 1.6+ :**

.attr() is deprecated for properties; use the new .prop() function instead as:

```
$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', true); // Checks it
$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', false); // Unchecks it
```

Comment: this also gives the same "Please select these options"

Answer (score 0):

try in this way:

```
$(document).find('input#FIRST').prop('checked', true); // Checks it
$(document).find('input#FIRST').prop('checked', false); // Unchecks it
```